# React Native: Render issue in iOS when upgrade from 0.42 to 0.47

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

I rencently upgraded my app from `RN 0.42` to `RN 0.47` and my app in iOS not rendering correctly, like this:
[image: Render not correctly]

Where I expect it to render like this:
[image: Expected]